# `Einsum is not implemented` error when convert onnx model to .pb model?

Tags: tensorflow, onnx

I am trying to convert onnx model to TensorFlow's .pb model. But when I do the `prepare` function, I got this error: `NotImplementedError: Einsum is not implemented.`
Are there some suggestions to solve this problem? Thanks!

By the way, here are the code I use to convert the model:

```
import onnx
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

def onnx2pb(model, pb_output_path, opset_version=12):
    tf_exp = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
    tf_exp.export_graph(pb_output_path)  # export the model

    
onnx_input_path = './model.onnx'
pb_output_path = './model.pb'
onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_input_path)
onnx2pb(onnx_model, pb_output_path)

>>> below are the error report

  tf_exp = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 66, in prepare
    return cls.onnx_model_to_tensorflow_rep(model, strict)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 86, in onnx_model_to_tensorflow_rep
    return cls._onnx_graph_to_tensorflow_rep(model.graph, opset_import, strict)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 143, in _onnx_graph_to_tensorflow_rep
    output_ops = cls._onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(onnx_node,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 254, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op
    exception.OP_UNIMPLEMENTED_EXCEPT(node.op_type)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/common/exception.py", line 30, in __call__
    super(OpUnimplementedException, self).__call__(op, version, domain)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnx_tf/common/exception.py", line 12, in __call__
    raise self._func(self.get_message(*args, **kwargs))
NotImplementedError: Einsum is not implemented.
[Finished in 5.3s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by changing `torch.einsum` to the correlated matrix multiplication :)